# Visual Studio 2013 - Hardware requirements and GPU accelaration

Tags: graphics-card, visual-studio, requirements, visual-studio-2013, wpf

On some of the computers in my company Visual Studio 2013 didn't work at all because the onboard graphics card wasn't good enough.
I checked for the requirements and found this:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 System Requirements]

This isn't so clear, I can't understand why some of the computers worked and others didn't and which onboard cards are supported.

I know that Visual Studio 2013 is implemented using WPF and that WPF is utilizing the GPU to perform better, but didn't find anything in the web to elaborate on it.

I would like to know what are the minimum GPU requirements and the recommended GPU requirements in order to work with Visual Studio 2013.

Will an external graphics card perform better than an onboard card?

Comment: which GPU do you use? What is not working? Inside the VS options you can turn off the HW acceleration to use software rendering.

Comment: These computers are Intel Core Duo E6550 with Intel's motherboards and onboard graphics cards, Visual Studio 2013 isn't starting and you cannot work with it.

Comment: this still doesn't include all details I want. Which GPU/chipset is it? Have you tried software rendering?

Comment: I had an issue with the onboard GPU in my machine and I couldn't even install VS2013. I fixed it by uninstalling the GPU drivers which then rolled me back to a Windows provided driver. Then installing worked OK and then I was able to load VS2013 and disable Hardware Acceleration and all has been working great since.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio can do software rendering, just like WPF. It should automatically detect your GPU and then use the correct rendering method. If that doesn't work, look at this KB article, it shows the registry key that control that behaviour: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2894215/en-us